# Spring boot Postmapping not working for request body with List

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to send array list JSON as request body in spring boot project but it gives me error. It it working fine if i just use json object.

I need to send request something like below.

```
[
    {
        "name":"abc"
.....
    }
]
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/addr")
public List<String> getAddr(@RequestBody List<Address> addr)
```

Address.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgConstructor
public class Address {
private String name;
....
}
```

when i hit this API it gives me following error
Error:

```
No primary or default constructor found for interface java.util.List]
```

Please suggest how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

This message implies that you are trying to use a default constructor for java.util.List.

Something like

```
new List();
```

If that's the case, try using ArrayList for example, because List is the interface, so you can only instanciate the implementation classes of List.